# SharePoint Online Delve

Tags: office-365, user-profile, my-site

Hi all I need to add logo and link in Delve page. SharePoint not support customization in Delve page.

How to add that any idea.

Also can i change the order of the display field like contact field first and aboutme after that

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess the order on the me.aspx page changes with the order in your editprofile.aspx. I would go to central admin -> user properties and there change the order to display the aboutme property after your contact information.